# While trying to initiate new Ps-Session it Stops Working in Script

Tags: session, powershell

I have a strange problem randomly Occurring.

Background : i Use a Script to Remote-Connect to a Server and plant a Sheduled-Task. While the Local Sheduled-Task is running i constantly check a Folder for a Log-file that tells me when the local script finishes.

Now i ran into some Strange problems. At first the Sleep loop i was in got left for no good reason. then i changed the code to create a new Powershell-Session every minute to make sure that the session wasn't dying.

Tonight the Problem happens again and at least the loop wasn't exited anymore. but the client wasn't able to build a new PS-Session after the 3 or 4th try.

Here's the Part of my Code. It works fine in 9 out of 10 Times.

```
      $SecurePassWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
      $Cred = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $Username, $SecurePassWord
      $pssessionoption = new-pssessionoption -operationtimeout 7200000 -IdleTimeout 7200000

      #i create a Session after that , plant a sheduled task and start waiting here.

     while (!(Invoke-Command -Session $Session -Scriptblock $CheckifClientDone))
       { 
        Remove-PSSession -Session $Session
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 120
        $doesitconnect = $false
        $CurrentPatchingState = "1;$Servername;Status=1;$(Get-Date -format 'dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss') Still Waiting" | Out-File -Filepath  "C:\Logs\Test_Logs\$Servername.txt" -Append -encoding ASCII 
        while (!($doesitconnect)){
        If ($counterfortimeout -eq 300){    #5 Hour timeout
            $CurrentPatchingState = "2;$Servername;Status=2;$(Get-Date -format 'dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss') Something went Wrong on the Client - Aborting after 5h of waiting" | Out-File -Filepath  "C:\Test_Logs\$Servername.txt" -Append -encoding ASCII 
            $CurrentPatchingState = "2;$Servername;Status=2;$(Get-Date -format 'dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss') Something went Wrong on the Client - Aborting after 5h of waiting" | Out-File -Filepath  "C:\Logs\Nagios\$Servername.txt" -encoding ASCII 
            exit
        }
        $counterfortimeout = $counterfortimeout + 1
        Try {
                $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ServerName -credential $Cred -sessionOption $pssessionoption -EA Stop
                $doesitconnect = $true          
            }
        Catch [system.exception]
            {
                $CurrentPatchingState = "2;$Servername;Status=2;$(Get-Date -format 'dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss') Could not create a Session with the Host at round $counterfortimeout ERROR :  $_.Exception.Message" | Out-File -Filepath  "C:\Logs\Test_Logs\$Servername.txt" -Append -encoding ASCII 
                $CurrentPatchingState = "2;$Servername;Status=2;$(Get-Date -format 'dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss') Could not create a Session with the Host at round $counterfortimeout ERROR :  $_.Exception.Message" | Out-File -Filepath  "C:\Logs\Nagios\$Servername.txt" -encoding ASCII  
                Remove-PSSession -Session $Session
                $doesitconnect = $false
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
            }
        }
        }
```

Here's Part of the Log : 
It Entered the loop at 03:01:22

```
     1;Server1;Status=1;03.12.2014 03:03:22 Still Waiting
     1;Server1;Status=1;03.12.2014 03:05:23 Still Waiting
     2;Server1;Status=2;03.12.2014 03:05:23 Could not create a Session with the Host at round 2 ERROR Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic..Exception.Message
     2;Server1;Status=2;03.12.2014 03:06:23 Could not create a Session with the Host at round 3 ERROR Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic..Exception.Message
     2;Server1;Status=2;03.12.2014 03:07:23 Could not create a Session with the Host at round 4 ERROR Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic..Exception.Message
     2;Server1;Status=2;03.12.2014 03:08:23 Could not create a Session with the Host at round 5 ERROR Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic..Exception.Message
     2;Server1;Status=2;03.12.2014 03:09:23 Could not create a Session with the Host at round 6 ERROR Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic..Exception.Message
     .
     .
     .
     2;Server1;Status=2;03.12.2014 08:03:24 Could not create a Session with the Host at round 300 ERROR Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic..Exception.Message
     2;Server1;Status=2;03.12.2014 08:04:24 Something went Wrong on the Client - Aborting after 5h of waiting
```

So he was definitely able to create a Session 3 times (one time before the loop and 2 times while in the loop)
I'm out of Ideas. is there a Timeout for the $Cred Object or the $SecurePassWord Object?
The Server was definitely reachable during the time. I tried creating a new Session this Morning and it works so its definitely not the Target blocking the connects.

UPDATE: thanks to the tip from ojk i captured the Error Message :

```
Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic..Exception.Message
```

Anybody got an idea? it happens 4 times this night with several hours in between. i cant wrap my head around.

Fun side fact. if i open a new Powershell window (while the running script still isn't able to connect). A new PS window is able to open a connection just fine. a Reboot on the target side doesn't fix the issue as well. so its definitely a Problem on the Server-side.

Edit: i uploaded a whole procmon loop of the powershell process. hers the result (too long to post it here fully) http://textuploader.com/oer3

Comment: Try to log the exception message itself as well, might tell you something. (you can use $_.Exception.Message in the catch block to get at it)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i added that to my script. Sadly i cant realy reproduce the error since it works 9 out of 10 times and microsoft only releases Patches only once a month. i will update the post as soon as it happens again. any other more generic ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Could it be that the session times out? Try setting the idletimeout of the pssessionoption to -1, which should disable the idle timeout completely. Be aware that doing this will mean it will use the WSMan shell timeout value instead I think.

Comment: How can the session time out if i open a new session every 60 seconds?

Comment: I don't know.. just throwing out ideas at this point. Sorry.

Comment: Updated with the actualy Error Msg.. i am still clueless though

Comment: Could you show us the relevant code where you are actually interacting with the registry?

Comment: thats the thing. im not interacting with the registry. all im doing is opening a pssession. the target might do stuff with the registry (installing windows updates) but not the server which is executing this script. Basicly look at the log i posted. the only difrence now is that i captured the error msg (registry) rest is still the same.

Comment: So, this error message you were able to catch.. that was written by the local script running in the task scheduler, right?

Comment: No that was generated by the Server trying to establish a connection. to sumarize again : the server builds up a pssession with a client. plants a sheduled task and then loops while the client script does stuff (update windows). in the loop he builds a new ps session every 60 seconds. checks if a specific logfile exists (test-path) then removes the session again and sleeps. the error occured after the first few loops (had it happen after 2 loops. on one of the others after 1 on the third after 5 loops.).

Comment: Ok, this is all very strange, and I'm sorry I don't have any clue how to fix this particular problem. Whenever I'm stuck in situations like this, I try to totally re-think my whole approach, and you might perhaps want to try something similar. What if you got the local (scheduled) jobs to write the log file to a share instead? Then you wouldn't need to use PSSession to check the log file for completed jobs? Just an idea.

Comment: Sadly isnt possible since i want to execute a reboot afterwards if needed so i will need another session. fun sidefact. if i try to build a new pssession outside of the runnign script (while the script still produces errors) it works just fine. also i updated the source post to make it more clear where i encountered the problem.

Comment: Ok. StackOverflow are beginning to complain about extended discussions, but if you want to contact me through twitter (@okallstad) we can see if we can get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Ok, I just can't leave this one alone :) A quick suggestion. Create the pssession object outside the loop, stored in a variable. Do not remove the session, just reuse the session object you already have inside the loop. Perhaps it's the constant creation/tear-down of the pssession that causes problems? It might be that the session stores info in the registry, and that this is what's making problems for you.

Comment: The Problem that that created was that the loop was exited unctronrollably when this error occured. thats why i started creating new sessions in the loop in the first place. this way i at least got the script to stay in the loop when a problem occours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Seems that the problem doesnt lie in the SCript itself but in the Windows Settings for Logging of Users.

I used http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2287297 and added the DisableForceUnload Registry key and am not able to Replicate the issue (before i was able by logging of after the script had started).

I will keep this marked as Resolved untill i run into the problem again.

it seems that starting this script not with a user but with ntauthority\system should have also solved the issue.... finding this was so painfull

Comment: Looking at the document you referenced, I can see the following note: This policy should only be used for cases where you may be running into application compatibility issues due to this specific Windows behavior. It is not recommended to enable this policy by default as it may prevent users from getting an updated version of their roaming user profile. I'd need to enable this on a server where people only connect to deploy new code. Any idea if this could cause problems to the users?